# Trying to make a loop to check the string for numbers only and negative numbers allowed in C++ im new to programming this is a class project

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a loop to check input strings for numbers only, and negative numbers are allowed.  I'm new to programming, this is for a class project.

This code works, to an extent.  When it shows the output, it does not show the first number, and does not allow `-` to be used. I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong in this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
string userInput;
int i = 0;
bool checkInput(int);


int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a numeric value : ";
        string userInput;
        cin >> userInput[i];
    }
    while (!checkInput(userInput[i]));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool checkInput(int input)
{
    string userInput;
    int i;
    cin >> userInput;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
        if (isdigit(userInput[i]))
        {
            cout << "\nYour input " << userInput << " is a valid numeric input." << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid numeric value: ";
            cin >> userInput[i];
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your function completely ignores the `input` it was passed and opts to read a new input in itself...is that intended?

Comment: In your main method, you are using an index, i, which is never incremented.

Comment: the function should show cin << userInput[i]; if this is what you were asking. No it was not intended

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you are not utilizing `std::string` correctly.

When `main()` prompts the user, it reads into a `char` of an empty `std::string`, which is undefined behavior.  You should be reading into the `std::string` itself without calling its `operator[]` at all.  `operator>>` has an overload for reading `std::string` values.

`checkInput()` is just all kinds of wrong.  It takes an `int` as input instead of a `std::string`, but ignores that input and waits for the user to type in *another* string value.  Then it loops through *that* string instead of the one read by `main()`, and only checks the 1st `char` before exiting.  If the `char` is a digit, `checkInput()` returns true, and `main()` exits.  Otherwise, `checkInput()` prompts the user to type in *yet another* `char` and then returns false, which then causes `main()` to prompt the user to type in *yet another* `char`. `checkInput()` does not actually loop through an entire string at all, and does no have any handling for the `-` character.

Try this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

bool checkInput(const string &);

int main()
{
    string userInput;

    cout << "Please enter a numeric value : ";
    do
    {
        cin >> userInput;
        if (checkInput(userInput))
            break;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    

        cout << "Please enter a valid numeric value: ";
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "\nYour input " << userInput << " is a valid numeric input." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool checkInput(const string &input)
{
    if (input.empty())
        return false;

    string::size_type i = 0;
    if (input[0] == '-')
    {
        ++i;
        if (i == input.length())
            return false;
    }

    do
    {
        if (!isdigit(input[i]))
            return false;    
    }
    while (++i < input.length());

    return true;
}
```

However, the best way to handle this situation is to simply not allow the user to enter non-integer values to begin with.  `operator>>` has overloads for reading integer values, both signed and unsigned types.  In this case, reading `int` values will suffice.  Let `cin` do all of the input validation for you:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userInput;

    cout << "Please enter a numeric value : ";
    while (!(cin >> userInput))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please enter a valid numeric value: ";
    }

    cout << "\nYour input " << userInput << " is a valid numeric input." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, i was going about this the wrong way and making it too complicated